# How to hidden searchBar in 2nd VC of same navigation Controller

Tags: swift, searchbar

Let's say I have 2 VC in same navigation Controller. In 1st VC (tableViewController), there is a search bar defined programmatically, and when click a row of tableVC, it will show(segue) 2nd VC(also tableVC).
[image]

Now the problem is that when the searchBar is active in 1st VC, e.g. input some word, then show the 2nd VC, the searchBar will also present in the 2nd VC. I want to hide the searchBar in the second VC. How could I do that since the searchBar is defined in the 1st VC? Any hint is appreciated.

/// update: try to hide searchBar in viewDidDisappear() of 1st VC, but together the navigation Bar is gone, which is not expected behavior.

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // hide searchBar
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
    }
```

/ / / Well, this code could remove searchBar in 2nd VC, but there is an animation of removing, which is not what I want even when I set `super.viewWillDisappear(false)`

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(false)

        // hide searchBar
        resultSearchController.isActive = false

    }
```

Comment: In 1St VC  viewWillDisappear() method,  try to hide searchBar definitely works and viewWilAppear() use to show when you dismiss 2nd VC.

Comment: I update my question, there is still some issues, please have a look.